# Same function in Python and Node.js returns different results

Tags: javascript, python, node.js

I am transitioning a project from Python to Node.js - everything has been going fine up until this point. I have a function that is supposed to convert the amount of EXP someone has into a level. I have attempted to rewrite the working function from Python into Node.js but the functions return completely different answers and I can't figure out why.

Python:

```
def calculateLevel(exp):
    if exp < 83: return 1
    else:
        calcExp = 0
        for level in range(1, 1000):
            diff = int(level + 300 * math.pow(2, float(level)/7))
            calcExp += diff
            if exp < calcExp//4:
                break
        return level
```

Node.js:

```
const _ = require("underscore");
// ...
function calculateLevel(exp) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (exp < 83) resolve(1);
        else {
            var calcExp = 0;
            for (var i in _.range(1, 1000)) {
                calcExp += parseInt(i + 300 * Math.pow(2, i/7));
                if (exp < Math.floor(calcExp/4)) {
                    resolve(i);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

For example, `calculateLevel(123456)` in Python returns `51` (the correct answer), but `await calculateLevel(123456);` in Node.js returns `15` (the incorrect answer).

Clearly there is something wrong in the Node.js version, but I can't figure out what it is.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: your `resolve(i)` is not in the same block than your `return level`, maybe you need to get it out of the loop

Comment: @jonatjano I just tried this, but unfortunately it gives the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python:

```
for i in range(1, 10)
   print(i)
```

Will create the sequence to `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9`

The [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) in JavaScript will iterate over the keys and not the values.

So `for (var i in _.range(1, 1000)) {`  will always be `0 ... 999`

Change it to [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)

```
function calculateLevel(exp) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (exp < 83) resolve(1);
        else {
            var calcExp = 0;
            for (var i of _.range(1, 999)) {
                calcExp += parseInt(i + 300 * Math.pow(2, i/7));
                if (exp < Math.floor(calcExp/4)) {
                    resolve(i);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Beside that it is not clear why you use a Promise here because you do not have any async code here. So you can completely remove the Promise here.

```
const _ = require("underscore");
// ...
function calculateLevel(exp) {
  if (exp < 83) return 1;
  else {
      var calcExp = 0;
      for (var i of _.range(1, 1000)) {
          calcExp += parseInt(i + 300 * Math.pow(2, i/7));
          if (exp < Math.floor(calcExp/4)) {
              break;
          }
      }
      return i;
  }
}

console.log(calculateLevel(123456))
```

Comment: This worked. Thanks for the answer! I'm new to Javascript, and most times I use a function, it returns `undefined` unless I use a promise or callback, and I find promises to be easier and cleaner than callbacks.

Comment: @L.Thompson updated the answer and added the same code without Promises and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (exp < Math.floor(calcExp/4)) {
                    resolve(i);
                    break;
                }
```

should be

```
if (exp < Math.floor(calcExp/4)) {
                        break;
                    }
resolve(i)
```

Comment: I just tested this but unfortunately it gives the same result.

Answer (score 0):

I ran this code:

```
function calculateLevel(exp) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (exp < 83) resolve(1);
        else {
            var calcExp = 0;
            for (var i=1; i<1000; i++) {
                calcExp += parseInt(i + 300 * Math.pow(2, i/7));
                if (exp < Math.floor(calcExp/4)) {
                    resolve(i);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }); }

console.log(calculateLevel(123456));
```

and it returned 51.

something else is probably causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding my opinion as you already have an accepted answer.

Although you convert a Python code block to Javascript, I feel you don't really have to use the same syntaxes and method names.

For an example, if we take the following code block in Python and JS;

Python:

```
def calculateLevel(exp):
    if exp < 83: return 1
    else:
        calcExp = 0
        for level in range(1, 1000):
            diff = int(level + 300 * math.pow(2, float(level)/7))
            calcExp += diff
            if exp < calcExp//4:
                break
        return level
```

Note: Here it uses `for level in range(1, 1000):`.

The same thing can be done by using a `while` loop as well. So it could look  something like:

```
level = 0
while level <= 1000:
    diff = int(level + 300 * math.pow(2, float(level)/7))
    calcExp += diff
    if exp < calcExp//4:
        break
return level
```

But looping over a `for in range()` in Python is more efficient than using a `while` loop. If I run a simple benchmark, I could see the following results.

> `for in range()` : 55 function calls in 0.000 seconds
>
> `while`: 1650 function calls in 0.001 seconds

Although this is the case with Python, it's quite different in Javascript (and in your approach which uses underscore's `range()` function.) Although the function names look similar, it doesn't mean they have same performance as in Python.

In fact, looping over `_.range()` is much slower than looping over a `while` loop. If you look at some benchmark results, you would see something like this:

`Using _.range(1, 1000)`: 67.67% slower

https://jsbench.me/b2jl4vvgnw/1

So with all that, I think it's better to write this using a while loop, and with a slight modification, I would write it as:

```
function calculateLevel(exp) {
    var level = 1;

    if (exp > 83){
        var calcExp = 0;
        while(level <= 1000){
            calcExp += parseInt(level + 300 * Math.pow(2, level/7));
            if (exp < Math.floor(calcExp/4))
                break;
            level++;
        }
    }
    return level;
}
```

Hope it helps!!